# Performance impact of using a string of length 100 characters as _Id column in Elastic Search

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am planning to store events in elastic search. It can have around 100 million events at any point time. To de-dupe events, I am planning to create _id column of length 100 chars by concatenating below fields
entity_id - UUID (37 chars) + 
event_creation_time (30 chars) + 
event_type (30 chars)

This store will be having normal reads & writes along with aggregate queries (no updates / deletes)
Can you please let me know if there would be any performance impact or any other side-effects of using such lengthy string _id columns instead of default Ids.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/mapping-id-field.html) field is **not indexed** and **not stored** by default so there is no performance issue `storage` wise.

Since you will be indexing millions of documents, the only major performance issue you will face is while `bulk indexing`. You have to make sure there is a `sequential pattern` to your `_id`s. From the [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#_other)

> - If you don’t have a natural ID for each document, use Elasticsearch’s auto-ID functionality. It is optimized to avoid
>     version lookups, since the autogenerated ID is unique.
> - If you are using your own ID, try to pick an ID that is [friendly to Lucene](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html). Examples include zero-padded sequential IDs, UUID-1,
>     and nanotime; these IDs have **consistent, sequential patterns that
>     compress well**. In contrast, IDs such as UUID-4 are essentially
>     random, which offer poor compression and slow down Lucene.

In that blog, long time Lucene committer Michael McCandless compares different ways of `_id` generation and IMO it is one of the finest articles I have read.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't need to index _id column as I will never query it directly. However if I understand correctly above suggestion of ensuring sequential pattern is in general best practice and my proposal mixing those indices totally breaks this as they are random generated. So even if I don't use bulk indexing, I should not do what I said in my post right? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, If it is not something application critical, then it is best to let ES handle _id generation

Comment: Ok. But identifying duplicate events is a primary requirement of my system and till now I found this is the only way to do it in ElasticSearch. Can you please suggest if there is any better way to achieve the same?

Comment: ohh, in that case your approach is the right one. I do some hashing in my own application. Also according to [this old post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/maximum-length-of-a-specified-document-id/4262), there is no limit.

Comment: isn't the blog post say if we don't pick something friendly to Lucene then reads will be slow but not writes? I am trying to understand how bulk writes will be slow if I were to pick say random hash for every doc?

Comment: Note that `_id` field is indexed per Elasticsearch documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html